# How to add autoprefixer with Svelte + vite app

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, svelte-component, autoprefixer

The autoprefixer that VSCode has doesn't seem to work just like it did with normal CSS. Can someone please help.

This is what I get in the console if I try to run Autoprefixer on my Component:

> [Autoprefixer] Autoprefixer Cannot execute Autoprefixer because there
> is not supported languages. Supported: LESS, SCSS, PostCSS and CSS.

Comment: Please add the error as text instead of an image.

Comment: error message:
Cannot execute Autoprefixer because there is not supported languages. Supported: LESS, SCSS, PostCSS and CSS.

Comment: i hope this could help
https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/vggw7r/how_to_use_autoprefixer_and_scss_together_in/